# How to get the full post date Blogspot

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, blogger, blogspot

Example code:

```
var postdate = entry.published.$t;
var month1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var month2 = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Mey","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
var d = postdate.split("-")[2].substring(0,2);
var m = postdate.split("-")[1];
var y = postdate.split("-")[0];
for(var u2=0; u2<month1.length; u2++){ if(parseInt(m)==month1[u2]){ m=month2[u2]; break;}}
var daystr = (showPostDate) ? '' + m + ' ' + d + ', ' + y + '' : "";
var item = '' + daystr + '';
```

The final product of the post date = Feb 17, 2013

I want to date format = Saturday, Feb 17, 2013

```
var daynames = ["Monday","Tuesday", ... "Sunday"];
```

Comment: need to use original data to create javascript `Date` object and work from there. Lots of resources on web to figure out how to parse it

Answer (score 0):

If you need formatting. You could use the post date to create a Date object. Like so:

```
var d = new Date(2013,2,17);
```

and use the d value to create your own date: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). See example at the bottom page of the link.

Use the following to get the day and retrieve from array:

```
getDay
Returns the day of the week (0-6) for the specified date according to local time.
```

Like so:

var day = ["Monday", "Tuesday", ....];
console.log(day[d.getDay()]);